# Pandas DataFrame 'Date' Column has no header / dtypes / not listed in df.columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm importing data from `nasdaqdatalink` api

Two questions from this:

- (1) How is this already a Pandas DataFrame without me needing to type `df = pd.DataFrame` ?
- (2) The 'Date' column, doesn't appear to be a DataFrame column? if I try `df.columns` it doesn't show up in the index and obviously has no header. So I am confused on what's happening here.

Essentially, I wanted to select data from this DataFrame between two dates, but the only way I really know how to do that is by selecting the column name first. However, I'm missing something here. I tried to rename the column in position [0] but that just created a new column named 'Date' with NaN values.

What am I not understanding? (I've only just begun learning Python, Pandas etc. ~1 month ago ! so this is about as far as I could go on my own without more help)

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kdCT.jpg)

Comment: 1) Because `nasdaqdatalink.get` returns a dataframe by default. It's smart for you.

Comment: 2) `Date` is the index, if you want it in the columns do `df = df.reset_index()`

Comment: @BeRT2me awesome this works! can you explain what this does in more detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's actually a better way, by keeping `Date` as the index, see the output of:

```
df.loc['2008-01-01':'2009-01-01']
```

---

`df.reset_index()` makes whatever the current index is into a column.

Comment: `Datetime` indexes are super useful, I'd keep them around whenever possible~